# python jproperties package failing to parse properties file with encoded strings

Tags: python-3.x, properties

### Purpose of the my code:

Read `.properties` file (Java's standard properties file) using `python`'s `jproperties` [package](https://pypi.org/project/jproperties/#:%7E:text=jProperties%20is%20a%20Java%20Property,property%20format%20is%20not%20supported.)

Sample from properties file:

```
# saved in a file lang.properties

Status=\u5e10\u6237\u73b0\u72b6
Reference=\u5411\u4e0a\u7684\u53c2\u8003
```

### Code section:

```py
from jproperties import Properties
prop = Properties()
with open('lang.properties', 'rb') as p:
    properties.load(p)
```

### Error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/PythonProjects/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jproperties.py", line 571, in _handle_escape
    codepoint = int(codepoint_hex, base=16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '6b\x00\x00'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/PythonProjects/main.py", line 46, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/myname/PythonProjects//main.py", line 39, in main
    load_properties(file)
  File "/Users/myname/PythonProjects/main.py", line 16, in load_properties
    properties.load(p)
  File "/Users/myname/PythonProjects/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jproperties.py", line 820, in load
    self._parse()
  File "/Users/myname/PythonProjects/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jproperties.py", line 741, in _parse
    while self._parse_logical_line():
  File "/Users/myname/PythonProjects/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jproperties.py", line 715, in _parse_logical_line
    value = self._parse_value()
  File "/Users/myname/PythonProjects/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jproperties.py", line 669, in _parse_value
    value += self._handle_escape(not single_line_only)
  File "/Users/myname/PythonProjects/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jproperties.py", line 603, in _handle_escape
    raise ParseError(str(e), start_linenumber, self._source_file)
jproperties.ParseError: Parse error in <unknown>:4276: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '6b\x00\x00'
```

Can you help me to avoid this error but still be able to load those lines in properties?